# Copy File to different directory in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsfilemanager

I want to copy a file from app resources to documents directory. I'm using this code, but this will copy the file to my own application documents directory.

```
NSFileManager* fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray  *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *storePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"TestFile.txt"];
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"TestFile" ofType:@"txt"];

[[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:filePath toPath:storePath error:nil];
if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:getDatabasePath])  {
    NSLog(@"file doesn't exist");
    // file doesn't exist
} else {
     NSLog(@"file exist");
}
```

Which I have try to change this code as, but it doesn't work maybe it's something like this

```
NSString *storePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"Applications/AppFolder/Documents/TestFile.txt"];
```

So is there any possible way to copy file to different directory?

Comment: I don't think you can access the files of the root directory. That's the good thing of having apps in a sandbox.

Comment: sorry this is HomeDirectory not a rootDirectory.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot copy resources of one application to other application from inside any application, because you will not get any reference of the other application. Each application has its auto generated application id and you cannot access that from other application.

If you are trying to achieve in the device, its impossible, but if you're trying something in simulator, just manually copy paste the resources..

Comment: Yes, i want to do that in the device how? can you suggest to me which possible way to do that on device? thank you.

Comment: You can't achieve this in device, nor in simulator, this can be achieved only by terminal commands like cp(but still it need a jailbroken device), but still you will have to identify the exact application folders thats not posible..

Comment: I believe there are a people's can do that method like many of jailbreak app can overwriting save game read/write plist in any of apps folder, and yea we're always on jailbroken devices. so i wonder how i can achieve like this apps?